# codeigniter 2.0 - Internal server error 500 when there is a database error

Tags: codeigniter-2, internal-server-error

Codeigniter 2.0 gives internal server error if there is a database error.

and this is how i have coded...

if($this->db->query($query))showerror();

but the the query method is throwing an error before the if condition gets executed.

i wanted to do condition check whether there is an error in the query or what ever the database error is and i dont want codeigniter to throw an error.

How do i do like what i think? this is how previous versions of CI worked.

Is there a specific reason to thrown an error with the HTTP status code of 500.

why it has been changed like this?

Comment: are you using latest version of php and mysql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which v2.0.x?

Internal 500 will happen if there is an error and no output. This will happen if its disabled (you've set the ENVIRONMENT to "production", and so will be hidden) or if your server will not display errors.

Make sure error_reporting(E_ALL) is happening, and ini option `display_errors = 1`.

Comment: i want it to work like the previous versions of CI. if there is a duplicate entry error then i dont want a 500 error. because the next line of my code does not work. this is not good. i dont want to alter the core code of CI to over come this.

Comment: Who said anything about altering core lines of code? By default the ENVIRONMENT does not change, meaning everything is default and everything is off. If you've changed this logic then it will whitepage on errors instead. If not, it's something else. Maybe your application does not have those two lines of code.

Comment: i was wondering something like this. i want the ENVIRONMENT to be in development and i dont want 500 errors... just like the old version of CI. so that i can check duplicate entries error no 1062.